# pas SQL query result to listView android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, listactivity

I have a problem in my list view. when I pass My SQL query to ListView then list view show this in each row
**com.MyPackageName.MyAppName.MyClassName@Some Number (like 2c62a7d0) **

I dont know why
this is my Function that return everything

```
public List<AddedZekrView> getAllRecordList(){
ArrayList<AddedZekrView> addedZekrFields = new ArrayList<AddedZekrView>();

//Cursor cursor= database.query(ZekrdbOpenHelper.TABLE_ZEKR, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

Cursor cursor= database.query(ZekrdbOpenHelper.TABLE_ZEKR, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Log.i("In while", cursor.getPosition()+"");

        AddedZekrView addedZekrFieldNew=new AddedZekrView();

        // you have to declare all fields such as **COLUMN_ID** in your addedZekrView activity

        addedZekrFieldNew.ID=cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ZekrdbOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID));
        addedZekrFieldNew.TITLE=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ZekrdbOpenHelper.COLUMN_TITLE));
        addedZekrFieldNew.DESC=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ZekrdbOpenHelper.COLUMN_DESC));
        addedZekrFieldNew.MAX_COUNT=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ZekrdbOpenHelper.COLUMN_MAX_COUNT));
        addedZekrFieldNew.CREATE_DATE=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ZekrdbOpenHelper.COLUMN_CREATE_DATE));
        addedZekrFieldNew.LAST_COUNT_DATE=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ZekrdbOpenHelper.COLUMN_LAST_COUNT_DATE));
        addedZekrFieldNew.MODIFY_DATE=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ZekrdbOpenHelper.COLUMN_MODIFY_DATE));
        addedZekrFieldNew.EXPIRATION_DATE=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ZekrdbOpenHelper.COLUMN_EXPIRATION_DATE));
        addedZekrFieldNew.START_AZ=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ZekrdbOpenHelper.COLUMN_START_AZ));

        Log.i("return cursor", addedZekrFieldNew.TITLE+ " " +addedZekrFieldNew.DESC);

        addedZekrFields.add(addedZekrFieldNew);
    }
}

//return List Object
return addedZekrFields;
```

}

and this is my java file:

```
public class AddedZekrView extends ListActivity {

public Long ID;
public String TITLE;
public String DESC;
public String MAX_COUNT;
public String CREATE_DATE;
public String CURENT_COUNT;
public String LAST_COUNT_DATE;
public String MODIFY_DATE;
public String EXPIRATION_DATE;
public String START_AZ;

ZekrDataSource datasource;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //PreferenceActivity is a subclass of ListActivity (source), so you can either remove the setContentView() method call or add a subview with id android.R.list in added_zekr_view.xml
    //I removed setContentView(R.layout.added_zekr_view);

    //setContentView(R.layout.added_zekr_view);

    datasource=new ZekrDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();



    List<AddedZekrView> addedZekrFields2 = datasource.getAllRecordList();

    // if this is first time that we run App so maybe we dont have any data on it so we need to check that
    //And call our list View again
    if (addedZekrFields2.size()==0) {

         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing Founded.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         toast.show();

        //datasource.insertRecord(null, null, null, null, null, null);
        addedZekrFields2 = datasource.getAllRecordList();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<AddedZekrView> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AddedZekrView>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, addedZekrFields2 );

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Can someone please help me to figure it out.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Overwrite toString() and it solve my problem :)